# when implementing Spring Security configuration getting java.lang.StackOverFlow

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure my `WebSecurityConfig` class for my `mySQL` database. What i m trying to achieve here is once user is created , automatically token will be created and assigned to the client. But i think i'm having problem about looking through all username's inside of the database.

So here is my `UserController`;

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/createuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createUser(@RequestBody User user, Model md) {
        if (userService.checkExistUserName(user.getUserName())) {
            md.addAttribute("LoginError", true);
            return "Username exists, try with another username";
        }
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setUserName(user.getUserName());
        newUser.setFirstname(user.getFirstname());
        newUser.setUserMail(user.getUserMail());
        newUser.setSurname(user.getSurname());
        newUser.setUserPassword(user.getUserPassword());
        userService.saveUser(user);

        /* Automatic login after register */
        securityService.autologin(user.getUserName(), user.getUserPassword());

        return user.getId().toString();
    }
```

**Here is the  `SecurityService`  class**

```
@Service
public class SecurityService {
    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

public User activeUser() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = auth.getName();
    Optional<User> user = userService.getUserByName(username);

    if (user.isPresent()) {
        return user.get();
    }
    return null;
}
public void autologin(String username, String password) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));

    authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

    if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    }
}
}
```

**Here is the  `WebSecurityConfig`  class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Service
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // disable caching
    http.headers().cacheControl();

    http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/createuser").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/1").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // We filter the api/login requests
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Create a default account

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return super.userDetailsService();
}
}
```

When i create an user , it creates to database, but gives me that error below;

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
```

It goes all the way bottom like that.

So i think the problem here is `UserDetailService` doesn't know how to search usernames in the database or it might be something else. I might not configure the `WebSecurityConfig class` properly. So any Suggestion?

Comment: You need to copy/paste the ENTIRE stack trace into your post and format it as code (use the `{}` button, or indent it all 4 spaces).

Comment: That's more, but still not ALL of it including all Caused By sections.  However, it looks like the Spring `UserDetailsServiceDelegator` has been configured to delegate to itself, which leads to infinite recursion. This could be a configuration problem OR a Spring bug.  Are you on the latest Spring release? If not, upgrade and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Your Hypothesis is rite. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#userDetailsServiceBean--
But how is spring suppose to know your database user loading logic.
Just let me know if you need some help with creating you custom UserDetailsService bean.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/30766106/18157 This may be a dup.  Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: This link is a bit complicated for me. I'm not sure what to do here.user1615664 It's 1.5.1 version of Spring boot Jim Garrison.

Comment: i already saw that question and i implemented the answer given at that [stackoverflow](stackoverflow.com/q/30766106/18157). I might having problem with configuration.